# Jest spyOn function called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write a simple test for a simple React component, and I want to use Jest to confirm that a function has been called when I simulate a click with enzyme. According to the Jest docs, I should be able to use `spyOn` to do this: [spyOn](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname).

However, when I try this, I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined` which I take to mean that my spy is undefined. My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {

  myClickFunc = () => {
      console.log('clickity clickcty')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro" onClick={this.myClickFunc}>
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and in my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme'

describe('my sweet test', () => {
 it('clicks it', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(App, 'myClickFunc')
    const app = shallow(<App />)
    const p = app.find('.App-intro')
    p.simulate('click')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
 })
})
```

Anyone have an insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You were almost done without any changes besides how you `spyOn`.
When you use the spy, you have two options: `spyOn` the `App.prototype`, or component `component.instance()`.

---

**const spy = jest.spyOn(Class.prototype, "method")**

The order of attaching the spy on the class prototype and rendering (shallow rendering) your instance is important.

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "myClickFn");
const instance = shallow(<App />);
```

The `App.prototype` bit on the first line there are what you needed to make things work. A JavaScript `class` doesn't have any of its methods until you instantiate it with `new MyClass()`, or you dip into the `MyClass.prototype`. For your particular question, you just needed to spy on the `App.prototype` method `myClickFn`.

---

**jest.spyOn(component.instance(), "method")**

```
const component = shallow(<App />);
const spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), "myClickFn");
```

This method requires a `shallow/render/mount` instance of a `React.Component` to be available. Essentially `spyOn` is just looking for something to hijack and shove into a `jest.fn()`. It could be:

A plain `object`:

```
const obj = {a: x => (true)};
const spy = jest.spyOn(obj, "a");
```

A `class`:

```
class Foo {
    bar() {}
}

const nope = jest.spyOn(Foo, "bar");
// THROWS ERROR. Foo has no "bar" method.
// Only an instance of Foo has "bar".
const fooSpy = jest.spyOn(Foo.prototype, "bar");
// Any call to "bar" will trigger this spy; prototype or instance

const fooInstance = new Foo();
const fooInstanceSpy = jest.spyOn(fooInstance, "bar");
// Any call fooInstance makes to "bar" will trigger this spy.
```

Or a `React.Component instance`:

```
const component = shallow(<App />);
/*
component.instance()
-> {myClickFn: f(), render: f(), ...etc}
*/
const spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), "myClickFn");
```

Or a `React.Component.prototype`:

```
/*
App.prototype
-> {myClickFn: f(), render: f(), ...etc}
*/
const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "myClickFn");
// Any call to "myClickFn" from any instance of App will trigger this spy.
```

I've used and seen both methods. When I have a `beforeEach()` or `beforeAll()` block, I might go with the first approach. If I just need a quick spy, I'll use the second. Just mind the order of attaching the spy.

---

EDIT:
If you want to check the side effects of your `myClickFn` you can just invoke it in a separate test.

```
const app = shallow(<App />);
app.instance().myClickFn()
/*
Now assert your function does what it is supposed to do...
eg.
expect(app.state("foo")).toEqual("bar");
*/
```

EDIT:
Here is an example of using a functional component. Keep in mind that any methods scoped within your functional component are not available for spying. You would be spying on function props passed into your functional component and testing the invocation of those. This example explores the use of `jest.fn()` as opposed to `jest.spyOn`, both of which share the mock function API. While it does not answer the original question, it still provides insight on other techniques that could suit cases indirectly related to the question.

```
function Component({ myClickFn, items }) {
   const handleClick = (id) => {
       return () => myClickFn(id);
   };
   return (<>
       {items.map(({id, name}) => (
           <div key={id} onClick={handleClick(id)}>{name}</div>
       ))}
   </>);
}

const props = { myClickFn: jest.fn(), items: [/*...{id, name}*/] };
const component = render(<Component {...props} />);
// Do stuff to fire a click event
expect(props.myClickFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/*whatever*/);
```

If a functional component is niladic (no props or arguments) then you can use Jest to spy on any effects you expect from the click method:

```
import { myAction } from 'src/myActions'
function MyComponent() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const handleClick = (e) => dispatch(myAction('foobar'))
    return <button onClick={handleClick}>do it</button>
}

// Testing:
const { myAction } = require('src/myActions') // Grab effect actions or whatever file handles the effects.
jest.mock('src/myActions') // Mock the import

// Do the click
expect(myAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foobar')
```

Comment: @Byrd I'm not sure what you mean. Is jest not working, `spyOn` not working, or something different? Is your `package.json` configured correctly for how you are configuring jest? So many questions about your statements.

Comment: If the question was "How do I use A to do B", but you knew that using C was a better route to achieve A, then it's probably appropriate to answer C. I've no issue with spyOn, but using it to spy on click handlers in React components is a rubbish approach to testing in 99% of situations.

Comment: @AlexYoung The method being spied is arbitrary. The path to get to the method is arbitrary. The example code had a flaw and it was addressed. Eventually, someone will have a use case for `spyOn` with components that don't accept `props`, or pure components without `state`. Spying a `prototype` has been 100% successful for me.

Comment: Does the code block after "Or a `React.Component.prototype`" demonstrate something different than the first code block?

Comment: @ZAD-Man - Yes. Handling a spy for prototypes and instances are slightly different. Do you want to trigger a spy on any instance's call to a method? Use the prototype approach. Do you want to trigger a spy on just a single instance's call to one of its methods? Use the instancing approach.

Comment: Can you give an example with a React functional component?

Comment: @VictorCarvalho This technique does not lend itself well to functional components. The goal here is to spy on class methods, which functional components do not have. I would suggest researching `testing-library/react` for your use-case.

Answer (score 31):

You're almost there. Although I agree with @Alex Young answer about using props for that, you simply need a reference to the `instance` before trying to spy on the method.

```
describe('my sweet test', () => {
 it('clicks it', () => {
    const app = shallow(<App />)
    const instance = app.instance()
    const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'myClickFunc')

    instance.forceUpdate();    

    const p = app.find('.App-intro')
    p.simulate('click')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
 })
})
```

Docs:
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html

Comment: Before the simulate click is called, call forceUpdate to attach the spy function to the instance:

    instance.forceUpdate()

Comment: Strange.. I couldn't get the above working for a similar test but changing the app render method from 'shallow' to 'mount' fixed it. Any ideas why this might've been the fix/Why 'mount' is not also required for this test?

Comment: @youngrrrr perhaps your function relies on the DOM, which shallow does not product, whereas mount is a full DOM render

Comment: the missing `forceUpdate` caught us out... seems strange though, can anyone explain?

Comment: This was not working for me - until I realised that the component under test was being wrapped by a Higher-Order Component. I needed to use `app.find("ActualComponent").instance()` instead to get the correct instance to monkey-patch the methods of

Comment: Any idea why this works when we force update :O. That is super freaky!

Answer (score 14):

In your test code your are trying to pass `App` to the spyOn function, but spyOn will only work with objects, not classes.  Generally you need to use one of two approaches here:

1) Where the click handler calls a function passed as a prop, e.g.

```
class App extends Component {

  myClickFunc = () => {
      console.log('clickity clickcty');
      this.props.someCallback();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro" onClick={this.myClickFunc}>
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can now pass in a spy function as a prop to the component, and assert that it is called:

```
describe('my sweet test', () => {
 it('clicks it', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();
    const app = shallow(<App someCallback={spy} />)
    const p = app.find('.App-intro')
    p.simulate('click')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
 })
})
```

2) Where the click handler sets some state on the component, e.g.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
      aProperty: 'first'
  }

  myClickFunc = () => {
      console.log('clickity clickcty');
      this.setState({
          aProperty: 'second'
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro" onClick={this.myClickFunc}>
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can now make assertions about the state of the component, i.e.

```
describe('my sweet test', () => {
 it('clicks it', () => {
    const app = shallow(<App />)
    const p = app.find('.App-intro')
    p.simulate('click')
    expect(app.state('aProperty')).toEqual('second');
 })
})
```

Comment: A class is an object. `spyOn` works with `ClassName.prototype`

Comment: A class is not an object.  In classical OO it is a blueprint for an object, in JavaScript it is a function.  `typeof (class A {}) === "function"`  When we instantiate a class we create an object, based on the class' prototype.  The prototype of a class is an object, and we could spy on methods if we wanted to.  Ultimately, as per my comments under your answer, we want to test the effect of a click handler, not just that it has been called.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem like the optimal solution is to avoid testing items like this and to instead test that either an import is properly called with the right arguments or that something is displayed that should now be displayed (see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58637912/8285811) for an example).

But I'll still add an alternative to actually "fix" the issue. In my situation I was using a functional component so the other answers didn't work. What I had to do was import the file into itself and call the problematic function that way...

```
// App.js
import * as thisModule from './App';

myClickFunc = () => {}

...
<p className="App-intro" onClick={thisModule.myClickFunc}>
  To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
</p>
```

It's a weird issue ([source1](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/6972#issuecomment-511015504), [source2](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082))