# how to test handleChange event function in react 16 using jest and Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I am trying test a compoenent using the jest and enzyme in react. The component has a handleChage event which is triggered on the when the dropdown button is clicked.

But I am getting a error message stating event.target.attribute is undefined.

Can anyone please correct me what am I missing or doing wrong?

Please find the code below:
Component code

**Component.js**

```
  handleChange = event => {
    if (event.target.attributes["value"]) {
      window.dataLayer.push({
        event: "customEvent",
        category: "dropdown",
        action: "select",
        label: "ABC",
        attribute1: "attribute1Value",
        attribute2: "attribute2Value",
        attribute3: "attribute3Value",
        attribute4: event.target.attributes["value"].value.toLowerCase()
      });
      this.setState({ stateName: event.target.attributes["value"].value });
    }
  };
```

**Component.test.js**

```
 it.only("should call handleChange reponse", () => {
const handleChange = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(
  <ComponentName
      triggerRequest={{
      triggers: {
        coverage:
          "ABC"
      }
    }}
  />
);

wrapper.find(".dropdown").simulate("click");
wrapper.instance().handleChange({});
expect(handleChange.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
// expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**The Error I get is**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

  213 |
  214 |   handleChange = event => {
> 215 |     if (event.target.attributes["value"]) {
      |                      ^
  216 |       window.dataLayer.push({
  217 |         event: "custom_event",
  218 |         category: "dropdown",
```

Thanks for the help and support in advance.

Comment: You are directly invoking the method on the wrapper instance with an empty object, which is causing that error. You should remove that and spy on the method within the component, or just test that some desired effect has occurred after simulating the click.

Comment: Hi @ChrisB. thanks for the update could you please share a little snippet of the code if you dont mind? Would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Hi I tried this code but no luck. 

**  wrapper.find(".dropdown").simulate("click");
    expect(handleChange.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);** it sims like there is new error now

Comment: I would look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860188/how-do-i-correctly-spyon-a-react-components-method-via-the-class-prototype-or-t) to learn about spying on a React method.

Comment: Hi I tried something smillar to the one you showed but again it says Error at toHavebeenCalled.

 `const spy1 = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "handleChange");
    wrapper.find(".dropdown").simulate("click");
    expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it("should call handleChange response", () => {
const wrapper = shallow(
  <ComopenentName
    triggerRequest={{
      triggers: {
        coverage:
          "coverage1,coverage2,"
      }
    }}
  />
);

 wrapper.find(".dropdown").simulate("click");
 const event = { target: { attributes: "Select a state" } };
 wrapper.instance().handleChange(event);
 wrapper.setState({ stateName: "ALASKA" });
 expect(wrapper.find("#dropdownItem").text()).toContain("ALASKA");
});
```

**Explanation:**

The above code triggers the function on a click of an button and when instance is updated with new state it checks if the stateName is present in the dropdown  or not.