# How can I test if a blur event happen in onClick event handler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a jest test for my inputBox component that include a button.
Have a function 'onClick' as a prop inside this component.

```
        <inputBox
            placeholder={'Type here..'}
            onClick={() => {inputRef.current.blur()}}
            button={true}
            ref={inputRef}
        />
```

I want to test the event 'inputBox is blur once I click the button'.
Below is the test code:

```
it('invokes blur after click button',() => {
    const onBlurSpy = jest.fn();
    const { getAllByRole } = render(inputBox);
    fireEvent.click(getAllByRole('button'))
    expect(onBlurSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Receive below error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

The `onBlurSpy` mock function isn't being called in the test because it isn't attached to the `inputBox` component. The blur function would likely need to be passed in as a prop to the component if you wanted to use `jest.fn()` to mock it.

If you want to check if the blur function has been called without adjusting the component's props, I'd recommend using [Jest's spyOn method](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).

Give the function you want to spy on a name so it can be referenced:

```js
<inputBox
     ...
     onClick={this.blurFunction}
     ...
/>
```

Then use Jest's `spyOn` function in the test:

```
const onBlurSpy = jest.spyOn(inputBox.instance(), "blurFunction")
```

I'd also recommend reading this [answer from a related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46735186/9737251) for some additional context.